# Flutter iOS 14 crash on Textformfield copy paste

Tags: flutter, ios14

Is anyone facing copy paste in ...

```
TextFormfield
```

copy paste functionality ? Please help me for below issues :

Configurations :

> os : 14.1
> device : iphone 6s
> flutter version : 1.22.1

Here is the firebase logs from Crashlytics:

> Precompiled_Stub_CallAutoScopeNative + 80
> Precompiled__EventHandler_15069316__timerMillisecondClock_15069316_1006 + 40

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22624

Comment: I have the same issue on real devices with OS 14.
Any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is resolved in :

> Stable Hotfix version : 1.22.4